# have an wifi issue...not showing connections..using 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.i have an issue with wifi.its not showing wifi connection..can someone help me on this?it's saying your computer is offline.I have tried everything.

Comment: Need more info. Make/model computer. Wireless interface info. More details please.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using network manager, download 'Wicd'

First uninstall network manager: sudo apt remove network-manager

Then download Wicd: Sudo apt install wicd

Then: sudo apt update

Sudo apt upgrade

Hopefully, that will work for you. It worked for me as I had the same wifi issue.

Comment: No, use Network Manager, and fix the real problem.